# GVF aos solver active contour

Tags: contour

I have successfully coded geodesic active contours using an aos solver and the Thomas algorithm - I will upload code if you would like. However, I can't get gradient vector flow forces incorporated. I just assumed I could replace the edge map with the gvf forces but this didn't work. Does any one have any experience with GVF using a Level set or do they know of any code that is available?

I appreciate that this is not a typical post but I can imagine many others would find a reply useful.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

http://barissumengen.com/level_set_methods/index.html provides a level set implementation of vector flows. Might c if I can introduce aos solver on top.

Comment: link is dead by now :(